# Create Anonymous object from Dictionary

Tags: c#, reflection, expandoobject

Today I got stuck at one point where I need to convert a `Dictionary<String,String>` to an anonymous object. Is there any one who has tried this before. Below is the example what I actually need.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
    { "CourseId", "XDX123BH" }, 
    { "PersonID", "JIHJ98KH" } 
};
```

Though this object I want to create is an anonymous object like:

```
new {CourseID = "XDX123BH", PersonId = "JIHJ98KH" }
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why anonymous objects? What is your source data?

Comment: Since you tagged your question with `ExpandoObject`, you already know about it. Have you tried it, and what did/did not work?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. How do you want to use the result? Why do you need to use an anonymous class?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but it needs another library called Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder and to include this into the project we need a Nuget version of 3.0 or above but In VS 2012 the latest version is 2.8. So I am unable to add it. So I am searching for some alternative.

Comment: You can update your nuget verson.

Comment: Here's some code on Github that does what you're asking: https://gist.github.com/theburningmonk/2221646

Comment: @WaqarAhmed It is showing me that I am already having a latest version of Nuget. Even I explicitly download it from Nuget official website but It is not installing the set up.

Comment: @JasonW It is giving me a compile time error of ToExpando() not defined.  I think I am using old version of DLLs.  I am using 4.0.0.0 version of IDictionary.

Answer (score -1):

You've your dictionary as

```
var input = new object();
var input2 = new object();

  var dict = new Dictionary<int, course<T1, T2>>
  {
    {1, new course<T1, T2> {CourseID =(T1)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T1)),
                            PersonID = (T2)Convert.ChangeType(input2, typeof(T2))}}
  };
```

You've a class as course

```
public class course<T1, T2>
{
   public T1 CourseID { get; set; }
   public T2 PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

Updated, this way you can pass everything into it. Parsing your input to the specific type.

Comment: Hey Christoph... My Dictionary is not predictable It varies from condition to condition.. meaning value can be any thing. You can say I want to pass dynamic parameter in a function.

Comment: Updated, give it a look. Maybe this is a bit of a push for you, to get to the solution.